# Examples of integrable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ but $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$.

Tags: calculus

> Examples of integrable functions $f$ and $g$ such that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$  but $\int_a^b f=\int_a^b g$.

Are there any functions that behave like this? If both functions are positive, then the integrals can be viewed as the area under the curves. Then most probably $\int_a^b f>\int_a^b g$. But I have another argument that seems to create possibility of such functions. I will use the Darboux' sum argument.

Let $\{Q_n\}$ and $\{R_n\}$ be the Archimedean Sequences of partitions of $f$ and $g$ respectively on $[a,b]$. Then it follows that $\{P_n\}=\{Q_n\}\cup\{R_n\}$ is an Archimedean sequence for both of them. Let $U(f,P_n)$ be the upper Darboux sum of $f$ for a fixed $n$. Then $U(f,P_n)>U(g,P_n)$ and
$$\int_{a}^{b}f= \lim_{n \to \infty} U(f,P_n) \geq \lim_{n \to \infty} U(g,P_n)=\int_{a}^{b} g.$$
So it seems like we can have such functions. Can anyone give some?

Thank you.

Comment: Such functions do not exist.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If no, is there any argument that can be made to eliminate the $=$ in $\geq$ in my proof (in the limit part)?

Comment: Are we talking about Riemann or Lebesgue integrals?

Comment: @ajotatxe Riemann integrals

Comment: The function $h=f-g$ is positive and integrable in $[a,b]$. So you can reduce the problem to find a strictly positive integrable function in $[a,b]$ whose integral is $0$. Or to prove that ot doesn't exist. If this $h$ exists, $\inf \{h(x):h\in[c,d]\}=0$ for every $a\le c<d\le b$. That implies that $h$ is not continuous in any interval.

Comment: @ajotatxe Ya, I could prove it that way. But I am just curious what arguments can I make to get rid of the possibilities I create in the proof.

Comment: To finish my argument, I need a theorem by Lebesgue that says that the set of discontinuities of a Riemann integrable function has measure $0$. Perhaps you can find a clue in the proof of that theorem. Alas, I don't have a link to the proof.

Comment: @Ho you said that one pair of the functions which satisfies this relation is $\sin{x}$ and $ \cos{x} $ in the interval $[0,\pi/2)$ , right?

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Yup

Comment: @ajotatxe Wow. Is it necessary to argue using measure theory?

Comment: Just take $a=b$.

Comment: Your example is mistaken. $\sin x -\cos x$ takes both positive and negative values on $[0,\pi /2)$

Comment: @ajotatxe . Measure theory can be avoided. See my A & my comment to it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $a<b.$ For $n\in\Bbb N,$ suppose there existed $[c,d]\subset [a,b]$ with $c<d,$ such that $\{x\in [c,d]: f(x)-g(x)\ge 1/n\}$ is dense in $[c,d].$ Then  any partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ has a refinement $Q$ in which $c,d$ are (not necessarily consecutive) end-points of some of the intervals of $Q.$ But then the upper Riemann sum $U(f-g,Q)\ge (d-c)/n, $ so $\int_a^b(f-g)\ge (d-c)/n>0.$

Therefore, for each $n\in \Bbb N,$ the set $B(n)=\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)-g(x)\ge 1/n\}$ is nowhere dense in $[a,b] .$ But then $[a,b]=\cup_{n\in\Bbb N}B(n)$ is the union of a countable family of nowhere-dense sets, contrary to the Baire Category Theorem.

So no such $f,g$ exist.

Comment: It is easier with Lebesgue integration. Let $m$ denote Lebesgue measure. $0=\int_a^b(f-g)\ge \int_{B(n)}(f-g)\ge m(B(n))/n$ implies $m(B(n))=0. $ But then $0<b-a=m([a,b])=m(\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}B(n))\le\sum_{n\in \Bbb N}m(B(n))=0$, a contradiction.